# Pass method as param Android

Tags: java, android, function, null

Hi guys I'm trying to create a function that checks null on an object before calling a function.

-If it's not null it calls the method otherwise it does nothing.

Example:

```
private Object object;

private void doSomething(){
    object().function();

    //or

    object(function())
}

public void object(){
    if(object != null){
        //in this case we would call 'function()'
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?
I wouldn't want a null pointer exception on `object().function();` if for example `object()` returned a `null` `Object`

Comment: Is "passing a function" possible: No. Is it necessary for what you are trying to do here: No.

Answer (score 1):

this will crash if object is null:

```
object.function();
```

do the classic way:

```
if object!=null

object.function();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize your object if it is null  inside your object method like this.

```
public Object object(){
    if(object != null){
        //in this case we would call 'function()'
        return object;
    }
   else{
     //initialize your object here and return it 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably better to not to return the initialized object in `else`, but call it's `function()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not pass a function reference as an argument, but you **can** pass a `Runnable` object like that:

```
private Object object;

private void doSomething(){
    Runnable functionRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            object.function();
        }
    };

    object(functionRunnable);
}

public void object(Runnable action){
    if(object != null){
        action.run();
    }
}
```

But in that case you don't have to. You can just check if the object is null in the `doSomething` method and call it if it is not:

```
if(object != null) object.function();
```